# Where can I find my serial number

Tags: identify-this-bike

I recently bought a bike online and I wanted to make sure it was the bike I paid for. I looked for the serial number on the bottom of the bike and couldn't find it. Where else would they put the serial number on a 24 inch Haro?

Comment: Please take the time to spell properly and tag your post "identify-this-bike". Typical locations are the bottom bracket area, dropouts, or head tube area.

Comment: I edited for language and clarity. I don't think the tag "identify this bike" is appropriate as the OP knows what bike he has, but I tried to find better tags.

Comment: I think identify-this-bike is appropriate -- the question is if this bike is a Haro or not.

Comment: I'm not sure how locating a serial number will identify the bike as genuine or not. I don't believe that Haro has a serial number lookup tool.  The OP would be better advised to seek other ways of trying to identify whether the bike is authentic.

Comment: Amending my comment: Haro itself doesn't have a serial number tool, but some owners have cobbled together their own registry. Added it to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This image from the City of Portland police shows the common places for bicycle serial numbers. Note that they are usually stamped and aren't very visible.

Note that one area not shown on this image is the head-tube. That's where my latest bike had it. Otherwise, my bikes all have it in location #4 (bottom of the bottom bracket) or behind the seat post.

[image]

Note this posting from Bike Forum which shows the Haro serial number stamped on the bottom bracket.

http://www.bikeforums.net/bmx/1089833-haro-identification-serial-number.html

There is also a registry of Haro bmx serial numbers, which might also help in identifying your bicycle:

http://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=206889

This latter registry is particularly useful because it has user-submitted photographs of serial numbers. While the majority are on the bottom bracket, some are stamped very faintly into the rear dropouts.