# Where could i find my serial number

Tags: serial-number

I was wondering where i can find the serial number on my merida j. 24 lite because I couldn't find it because I am looking at selling it

Comment: You might check this answer from a similar question: [link](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44584/where-can-i-find-my-serial-number)

Answer (score 1):

Serial number is almost always in the frame, near the bottom bracket area. On my Brompton, it's at the bottom of the seat tube. It may also be at the bottom of the downtube or below the bottom bracket.

I would assume most bike frames today have a serial number, but it's not impossible to not have a serial number. Each serial number is specific to manufacturer, so theoretically it's possible to frames from different manufacturers would have the same serial number.

Comment: Sometimes it's somewhere on the head tube.